# Backing-up computer with FTP or SSH

Tags: ssh, backup, 16.10, ftp, ubuntu-gnome

I recently bought a new computer. Is it possible to make a full backup from my old computer into the new computer using FTP or SSH? If so, how could I do that? Knowing that both computer use Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: Do you want to *clone* the system to the other computer, do you want to write a complete *image* of the old system into the other computer, or do you want a 'full backup of the files' from the old computer in the new computer.? There are many ways to make a backup.

Comment: @sudodus Yes, to all those questions. I want to clone the system to the other computer. I know there exists many ways to do that, but I'd like to use FTP or SSH if possible.

Comment: Please stop editing the tags on your post.  Repeatedly doing this generates noise and can be considered an abuse of the system because it constantly bumps your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a compressed image with Clonezilla. This cloned copy is a directory with some files. It is possible to recover the cloned system from the cloned copy into another hard disk drive of at least the same size (for example if the original one is damaged). A cloned copy of the whole drive is complete and therefore easier to use than a copy of a single partition or a few partitions.

Clonezilla can work locally as well as via the network. I use it both ways, and it uses ssh/sftp via the network. I have been using Clonezilla for several years now, and I am still using it in 'beginner mode' most of the time (it is powerful enough for me, and helps me do the things in the correct way).

Detailed tutorials can be found via the internet. I suggest that you start looking at Clonezilla's home page,

http://clonezilla.org

Answer (score 1):

You've indicated that both machines are Ubuntu 16.10 so presuming that they have their own identifiers (e.g. UUIDs) that you want to preserve and not start to have to address any changes by an overwrite (like in `fstab`).

The following should do what you are looking for (executed on the destination PC):

```
sudo rsync -aAXvP --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found","/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/*","/etc/network/interfaces"} username@hostname:/* /
```

As you've explicitly referenced `ssh`, note that `rsync` can accept the necessary arguments with the `-e` option.
For example:

```
-e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null"
```

You'll need to provide the specific `ssh` options for your environment (like keys if in use, etc.)

I'd recommend trying a simple folder transfer between devices to ensure all mechanics operate as intended before the larger network migration.